# Сформировать КЛАДР вручную

Tags: кладр

Есть сайт (ссылку дать не могу, там нужен логин) с полями заполнения адресов РФ. Есть поле Региона РФ, поле Района, поле Города и поле населённого пункта.

При заполнении поля отправляется запрос на сервер в котором приходит JSON со списком данных для заполнения следующего поля в формате `{"Code":"","Name"}`.

Например, я выбираю костромскую область, отправляется запрос, и в ответ получаю список районов: `{"Code":2,"Name":"Антроповский р-н"}, ...`, выбираю район, отправляется запрос, в ответе список населённых пунктов. Сразу после этого я нажимаю кнопку "сохранить" и отправляется запрос в теле которого уже есть код КЛАДР (Пример: `"KLADRCode": "280070000320000"`), а значит он формируется каким-то JavaScript. Найти не смог поэтому пишу сюда.

Если у меня коды Региона, Района\Города\Населённого пункта, можно ли сформировать КЛАДР вручную?

Первые две цифры, точно отвечают за субъект РФ. Последние 5 или 6 за населённый пункт, вроде, а перед ними район. Но это всё просто пальцем в небо.

Answer (score 1):

Короче, с помощью [этого](https://kladr-rf.ru/) сайта понял структуру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
ХХ-ХХХ-ХХХ-ХХХ-ХХХХ
РГ-РЙН-ГРД-НСП-УЛИЦ
```

Код на js для формирования КЛАДР:

```
function KLADR(region, district, city, town, street=0)
{
var rS = String(region).padStart(2,'0');
var cS = String(city).padStart(3,'0');
var dS = String(district).padStart(3,'0');
var tS = String(town).padStart(3,'0');
var sS = String(street).padStart(4,'0');

return rS+dS+cS+tS+sS;
}
```

Использование:

```
KLADR(70, 15, 0, 11)     // Томская область, Чаинский район, деревня Григорьевка
KLADR(31, 0, 1, 0)       // Белгородская область, город Белгород
KLADR(78, 0, 0, 0)       // город Санкт-Петербург
KLADR(44, 0, 3, 0, 666)  // Костромская область, город Кострома, ул. Металлистов
```

Справочник регионов РФ:

```
var ruStates = new Object({
"1":"Республика Адыгея (Адыгея)",                                 
"2":"Республика Башкортостан",                                    
"3":"Республика Бурятия",                                         
"4":"Республика Алтай",                                           
"5":"Республика Дагестан",                                        
"6":"Республика Ингушетия",                                       
"7":"Кабардино-Балкарская Республика",                            
"8":"Республика Калмыкия",                                        
"9":"Карачаево-Черкесская Республика",                            
"10":"Республика Карелия",                                         
"11":"Республика Коми",                                            
"12":"Республика Марий Эл",                                        
"13":"Республика Мордовия",                                        
"14":"Республика Саха (Якутия)",                                   
"15":"Республика Северная Осетия - Алания",                        
"16":"Республика Татарстан (Татарстан)",                           
"17":"Республика Тыва",                                            
"18":"Удмуртская Республика",                                      
"19":"Республика Хакасия",                                         
"20":"Чеченская Республика",                                       
"21":"Чувашская Республика - Чувашия",                             
"22":"Алтайский край",                                             
"23":"Краснодарский край",                                         
"24":"Красноярский край",                                          
"25":"Приморский край",                                            
"26":"Ставропольский край",                                        
"27":"Хабаровский край",                                           
"28":"Амурская область",                                           
"29":"Архангельская область",                                      
"30":"Астраханская область",                                       
"31":"Белгородская область",                                       
"32":"Брянская область",                                           
"33":"Владимирская область",                                       
"34":"Волгоградская область",                                      
"35":"Вологодская область",                                        
"36":"Воронежская область",                                        
"37":"Ивановская область",                                         
"38":"Иркутская область",                                          
"39":"Калининградская область",                                    
"40":"Калужская область",                                          
"41":"Камчатская область",                                         
"42":"Кемеровская область",                                        
"43":"Кировская область",                                          
"44":"Костромская область",                                        
"45":"Курганская область",                                         
"46":"Курская область",                                            
"47":"Ленинградская область",                                      
"48":"Липецкая область",                                           
"49":"Магаданская область",                                        
"50":"Московская область",                                         
"51":"Мурманская область",                                         
"52":"Нижегородская область",                                      
"53":"Новгородская область",                                       
"54":"Новосибирская область",                                     
"55":"Омская область",                                             
"56":"Оренбургская область",                                       
"57":"Орловская область",                                          
"58":"Пензенская область",                                         
"59":"Пермская область <*>",                                       
"60":"Псковская область",                                          
"61":"Ростовская область",                                         
"62":"Рязанская область",                                          
"63":"Самарская область",                                          
"64":"Саратовская область",                                        
"65":"Сахалинская область",                                        
"66":"Свердловская область",                                       
"67":"Смоленская область",                                         
"68":"Тамбовская область",                                         
"69":"Тверская область",                                           
"70":"Томская область",                                            
"71":"Тульская область",                                           
"72":"Тюменская область",                                          
"73":"Ульяновская область",                                        
"74":"Челябинская область",                                        
"75":"Читинская область",                                          
"76":"Ярославская область",                                        
"77":"г. Москва",                                                  
"78":"г. Санкт-Петербург",                                         
"79":"Еврейская автономная область",                               
"80":"Агинский Бурятский автономный округ",                        
"81":"Коми-Пермяцкий автономный округ <*>",                        
"82":"Корякский автономный округ",                                 
"83":"Ненецкий автономный округ",                                  
"84":"Таймырский (Долгано-Ненецкий) автономный округ",             
"85":"Усть-Ордынский Бурятский автономный округ",                  
"86":"Ханты-Мансийский автономный округ - Югра",                   
"87":"Чукотский автономный округ",                                 
"88":"Эвенкийский автономный округ",                               
"89":"Ямало-Ненецкий автономный округ",                            
"99":"Иные территории, включая город и космодром Байконур"});
```